# Prove a series of combinations will always equal 1

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

This is a simple problem that just uses the basic combination formula $C_{(n,k)}$ for the number of possible combinations of k objects taken from a set of n objects. Where $n\geq1$ and $1\leq k \leq n$, 

$$C_{(n,k)}={n!\over k!(n-k)!}$$

I'm working on a larger problem involving counting elements of overlapping sets and subsets without redundancy. As part of this, I've run into the series $S_n$, where

$$S_n=C_{(n,1)}-C_{(n,2)}+C_{(n,3)}-C_{(n,4)} \cdots \pm C_{(n,n)}$$

where $n$, the number of objects being selected from, remains the same for the entirety of the series, but where $k$ starts at $k=1$ and increases incrementally throughout the series until $k=n$. 
The combinations are alternatively added and subtracted, starting with the addition of the first combination.

**Examples**:

$$S_1={1! \over 1!(1-1)!}=1$$

$$S_2={2! \over 1!(2-1)!}-{2! \over 2!(2-2)!}=2-1=1$$

$$S_3={3! \over 1!(3-1)!}-{3! \over 2!(3-2)!}+{3! \over 3!(3-3)!}=3-3+1=1$$

$$S_4={4! \over 1!(4-1)!}-{4! \over 2!(4-2)!}+{4! \over 3!(4-3)!}-{4! \over 4!(4-4)!}=4-6+4-1=1$$

I've only played around with this series for a handful of values of $n$, but **it seems that for all $n$, $S_n=1$. How would you prove this?**

I have very little idea how to go about it, and am particularly having trouble with cases where $n$ is even. One not very helpful thing is that the last combination in any $S_n$, $C_{(n,k)}$, will in itself always be equal to $1$, so one could just prove that the series excluding that, up til $k=n-1$, will be equal to $0$.

Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: You know that $C_{(n,k)} = C_{(n,n-k)}$. Try using that fact to group terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that by the  **Binomial Theorem**, 
$$(1-x)^n=\binom{n}{0}-\binom{n}{1}x+\binom{n}{2}x^2-\binom{n}{3}x^3+\cdots.\tag{1}$$

Set $x=1$. We get that the sum (1) is equal to $0$, from which you can quickly conclude that your sum is always $1$. 
Just write 
$$\binom{n}{0}-\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}-\binom{n}{3}+\cdots=0,$$
and bring all but the first term to the right-hand side.

Answer (score 0):

Proposed solution as follows :

[image]